# Using the new operator or declaring variables in a loop?

Tags: java

It seem like you can declare Scanner completely inside the loop and it will work just fine.
I have read that you should give you variables the smallest scope possible. Does this mean that the following code I wrote is incorrect?

```
Scanner SeatScan;
int x = 0,y = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    SeatScan = new Scanner(seats.get(i));
    if(SeatScan.hasNext()){
        x = SeatScan.nextInt(); 
        y = SeatScan.nextInt();
    }
    people.add(new Person(x,y,names.get(i))); 
}
```

Is this better

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    int x = 0,y = 0; 
    Scanner SeatScan = new Scanner(seats.get(i));
    if(SeatScan.hasNext()){
        x = SeatScan.nextInt(); 
        y = SeatScan.nextInt();
    }
    people.add(new Person(x,y,names.get(i))); 
}
```

Won't the loop declare and reassign the x and y values to 0 after each iteration and re-declare the Scanner over and over again(although It probably doesn’t do that)? Also for the first code I don't get a warning from eclipse to close my scanner. 
If i do close it it says "Scanner was not initialized"?. For the second version it says resource leak, scanner is never closed. What is going on here and how should I declare my variables from now on when working with loops?

Comment: that depends.. on whether you want to use x and y outside the loop... it makes no difference otherwise..

Comment: Sidenote: You should start all your variable names with a lowercase letter - that's the convention in Java (unless the variable is final).

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner seatScan` is a *reference* not an object.  The JVM is smart enough to allocate all the local variables at the start of the method so nesting the variable will not impact performance. i.e. it is not creating and destroying something at runtime.

If you look at the byte code for this method (and you have debugging information) you will see there is one table at the end for all local variables for the whole method.

BTW: You might what to only create a Person if there is valid input.

In short, unless you know you have a performance issue because you measured it, you should assume that the clearest, simplest code will also run fast enough.

If I was going to change anything, I would use Java Coding Conventions and use variables which start with a lower case character e.g. `seatScan` not `SeatScan` which looks like a class name.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your need, where in the program you want to use your variables. as per your code snippet 2nd approach seams to be more fitting.

Just close scanner after the if block and add a valid value check for x and y.

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    int x = 0,y = 0; 
    Scanner seatScan = new Scanner(seats.get(i));
   if(seatScan.hasNext()){
    x = seatScan.nextInt(); 
    y = seatScan.nextInt();
   }

   seatScan.close();
   if(x!=0 && y!=0) {
      people.add(new Person(x,y,names.get(i))); 
   }
}
```